# Arduino Beetle and Camera

Tags: arduino, camera

What is the best way to physically connect a night-vision Raspberry Pi [camera module](http://www.waveshare.com/rpi-ir-cut-camera.htm) (embedded with an IR-CUT filter) to this [Beetle](https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Beetle_SKU:DFR0282) micro-controller board (essentially a minimalized version of Arduino Leonardo)?

I've considered:

- FFC to USB adapter
- Removing FFC adapter, connecting wires directly to the board
- CSI->HDMI->USB

Comment: Just connect it to a Pi, and use [Motion](https://motion-project.github.io/) to do your time lapse snaps.  Or use [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/) on a supported camera.  Or use the Arduino to trigger a plain digital camera to take pictures a some specified interval.  Driving that camera and storing the data using an Arduino is a task for masochists with too much time on their hands and an electronics fetish.

Answer (score 5):

None.  That high speed synchronous serial camera is simply not compatible with an Arduino.  Nor is USB an option - the Arduino can only be a USB device, which means it cannot talk to another USB device, but only to a USB host.

Generally speaking, trying to put *any* sort of camera on an Arduino is a severe mistake - not only are there no efficient interfaces, there is also insufficient RAM to do much with the result.

The solitary exception would be buffered cameras permitting slow readout, but even there, it's generally a mistake to try to use a little ATmega for anything image related.

You need to pick a more appropriate platform for your *unspecified* image tasks.  Note that parts selection questions are generally off-topic here.

Comment: I don't need a live feed.  This is for occasional static images.  I'm trying to make a time lapse video of a crystal patch in a small space.  I need some way of taking a picture every hour or so within an area no greater than 35mm, the smaller the better.

Comment: An Arduino is still an extremely wrong choice.